# Send Email alert on low Disk or RAM

Tags: powershell, email, windows-server-2012-r2, alerts

I tried several Scripts to email the status of HDD or RAM but its not working,
1st Time using PowerShell.

Windows Server 2012 R2

Script would get triggered by the event (when the Memory is low) and send the email with the details.

to get the Disk Stats i used

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 2013}
```

How can i add this event to the email and make it appear in the message, i tried giving it a name like

```
$event Get-EventLog -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 2013}
```

but i don't know how to add it to the message body its not like java or

```
$message.body = $body + $event
```

to send email this script works,

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "username@gmail.com"
$Password = "zxc"

$to = "help@x.com"
$cc = "help@x.ae"
$subject = "Low Disk Space"
$body = "The Server Disk is Low on memory"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.Body = $body
$message.To.add($to)
$message.Cc.add($cc)
$message.From = $username

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.Send($message)
Write-Host "Mail Sent"
```

I read that the email alerts were discontinued by MS but people still have ways of doing it, unfortunately I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Something to help you get started on this:

```
# We first need to know which command to use
Get-Command '*mail*'

# We use the splatting technique to provide the parameters
$Params = @{
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Port       = '587'
    From       = $username
    To         = 'help@x.com'
    Cc         = 'help@x.ae'
    Subject    = 'Low Disk Space'
    Body       = 'The Server Disk is Low on memory.'
}

# Get-Help explains what this CmdLet does
Get-Help Send-MailMessage

# Get-Help can also give you examples on how to use the CmdLet
Get-Help Send-MailMessage -Examples

# Retrieve only events of the last 24 hours and select the first one
$Today = Get-Date
$Past = $Today.AddDays(-1)
$Event = Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $Past | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6013} | Select-Object -First 1

# Add the event to the mail body
$Params.Body += ' ' + $Event.Message

# Send the mail
Send-MailMessage @Params
```

This script can then be added to the `Task-Scheduler` to run once a day.

Comment: So, i need to add a few more things to this script you posted, its not complete correct. Username is missing and the password or this what you posted is a reference which i need to adjust based on the help messages.

Comment: @Admir He's giving you a starting point, explaining the different functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SCHTASKS /Create /RU "SYSTEM" /SC DAILY /ST 17:30 /TN DailyHDDMemReport /TR "powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\Temp\file.ps1'" /F
```

This will create a daily task that runs a powershell script specified at 5:30 as SYSTEM in conjunction with DarkLite1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

After many writing may scripts and working on it, due to increased requirements script after script, the feature requirement made me in the end use the free option of the following tool.

Has more than needed

https://www.manageengine.com/network-monitoring/

Regards